# Setting isLoggedIn true or false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, frontend, conditional-operator

Currently When I am logged in or out my content is hidden. I want my content to show when logged in, but hidden when logged out.
I want to write a ternary and to set a token that is either true or false to determine if a user will see or will not see my content.

If someone could show me in a clear and simple way how to solve this issue it would be great.
How can I render either true or false here based off of whether a user is logged in or not?

Comment: **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Please [edit] your question to include the text.

Comment: You can use `localstorage` for storing token and removing it when user logged out. If the token is present in local storage, show content or else hide content

Comment: I'm not actually sure how to do that in the code actually. I have a ProtectedRoutes.jsx file and I'm not sure how to write the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example of how to display content according to a state :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      {isLoggedIn ? <div>Content that is visible when logged in</div> : null}
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

If login operation is successful when you log in for the user, save the access token to localstorage.

```
const user = localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.access);
```

then where you need to check

> if(localStorage.getItem('token') !== undefined) {
> --the part you want to hide }

NOTE: If there are other user data you get from JWT. (user_name, user_id, image, permission.. ) this is not the best practice.
If your project is big and you need information as I mentioned above. You must first decode the JWT and then create the localstorageta user.